# Is there any widget in Dojo similar to JPanel in Java

Tags: dojo

is there any widget in Dojo similar to JPanel in Java ( to load image , some text above and buttons at bottom ) or I need to use div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dijit (Dojo's widget toolkit) offers some container and layout widgets, such as BorderContainer which provides specific layout patterns, but Dijit generally doesn't try to wrap HTML concepts.  If you just need simple controls, use HTML and CSS.  Perhaps you should just be using DIVs here.

Dijit does provide a container widget for HTML called ContentPane, mostly for use in widget hierarchies or where ajax loading via href is required.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what a jpanel is, but looking at http://www.google.co.uk/images?q=JPanel&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=og&sa=N&hl=en&tab=wi&biw=1920&bih=1043 I'd suggest using a `dijit.layout.BorderContainer`

See http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.6.0/dojo-release-1.6.0/dijit/tests/layout/test_BorderContainer_full.html