# Movable JPanels or Widget like JPanels

Tags: java, swing, widget, jpanel

I'm looking for an external API (or internal) that gives me the ability to make movable JPanels or widget like JPanels. What I mean by this is, for example, clicking the JPanel and moving it around to the desired location in the frame. Is this possible in Java? I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353528/is-there-any-widget-in-dojo-similar-to-jpanel-in-java) but I don't think it is what I am looking for.

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) should give you some ideas. It's built into Swing.